# Not able to fetch titles of a website using BS4

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://youtube.com/"
r = requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')

title = soup.title()
print(title)
```

Been getting an empty list as an output for this.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://youtube.com/"
r = requests.get(url)
htmlContent = r.content

soup=BeautifulSoup(htmlContent, 'html.parser')

title = soup.find("title").text
print(title)
```

or

```
title = soup.title.text
```

Comment: Yeah this works, any idea why the regular mine doesn't work?

Comment: you can get tag data by simply using the tag name like soup.title, soup.head, soup.body etc. title() method is not available

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a typo - simply remove the `()`  to get the `<title>`:

```
soup.title
### <title>YouTube</title>
```

Add `.text` to get the text of the `<title>`:

```
soup.title.text
### YouTube
```

Comment: Any reason why "text" is used